# Cannot specify flags when using variables for Docker agent args?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am attempting to mount a volume for my Docker agent with Jenkins pipeline. The following is my JenkinsFile:

```
pipeline {
    agent none
    environment {
        DOCKER_ARGS = '-v /tmp/my-cache:/home/my-cache'
    }
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            agent {
                docker {
                    image 'my-image:latest'
                    args '$DOCKER_ARGS'
                }
            }
            steps {
                sh 'ls -la /home'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sadly it fails to run, and the following can be seen from the pipeline.log file.

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to run image 'my-image:latest'. Error: docker: Error response from daemon: create  /tmp/my-cache: " /tmp/my-cache" includes invalid characters for a local volume name, only "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]" are allowed. If you intended to pass a host directory, use absolute path.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

However, the following JenkinsFile *does work*:

```
pipeline {
    agent none
    environment {
        DOCKER_ARGS = '/tmp/my-cache:/home/my-cache'
    }
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            agent {
                docker {
                    image 'my-image:latest'
                    args '-v $DOCKER_ARGS'
                }
            }
            steps {
                sh 'ls -la /home'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The only difference is the `-v` flag is *hardcoded* outside of the environment variable.

I am new to Jenkins, so I have struggled to find any documentation on this behaviour. Could somebody please explain why I can't define my Docker agent `args` entirely in an environment variable?

Comment: I would try replacing the single quotes with double quotes. Not sure if the parsing has anything to do with the quotes.

Comment: Can't do that unfortunately, because then `$DOCKER_ARGS` would be interpreted as a Groovy variable, whereas I intend it to be parsed by Jenkins directly as it is.